# how to perform zoom in/zoom out through adb on a device?

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, adb, ui-automation

I want to perform an automated zoom in and zoom out function through adb. I have recorded the event log through getevent command and tried to replay it through sendevent but it does not work smoothly and even the zoom is not performed as it was carried out in reality.

Is there something like "adb shell input swipe" command where I can pass the coordinates as well.

Comment: `sendevent` works just fine for sending "pinching" gestures - so it is a problem with your implementation

Comment: isnt it responding slowly and and making it look as long press event?